# How to make available the HttpServletRequest to a servlet method interceptor

Tags: java, guice

I am starting servlets using the guice filter. I intercept, using `MethodInterceptor` all the doGet() calls on the servlet. On the method interceptor, I what the `HttpServletRequest` to be available. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

MethodInterceptor interface has `public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation)` method. And you can get method arguments when implementing this method like this:

```
Object [] args=invocation.getArguments();
```

In this way you can get 2 arguments passed to doGet : HttpServletRequest req and HttpServletResponse resp.

Comment: Hello, I have a problem with custom functions present on the servlet that I am also trying to intercept, but they don't take HttpServletRequest as argument. Is there a way to inject the HttpServletRequest into the interceptor?

Comment: You can add a `@Inject Provider<HttpServletRequest> requestProvider` field to your interceptor and use `Module.requestInjection()` on the interceptor, I believe.

Comment: Can you show the code of your method interceptor and how you intercept method calls?